# Как сделать так, чтобы дочерние элементы flex-box были друг на друге?

Tags: css, вёрстка, slider, flexbox

Делаю слайдер. Хочу сделать так, как сказано в заголовке. Это нужно, чтобы управлять слайдером только через `opacity`. Основная проблема в том, что, если дочерним элементам поставить `position: absolute`, то родитель схлопывается, а мне нужна его рамка.

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}
.div{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="div">1</div>
 <div class="div">2</div>
 <div class="div">3</div>
 <div class="div">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообщем, решение пришло уже в тот момент, когда оформил вопрос. Не пропадать же добру)

Для того, чтобы родитель не схлопывался и можно было работать с его рамкой, нужно одному из дочерних элементов установить `position:relative`.

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}
.div{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.div:first-child{
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="div">1</div>
 <div class="div">2</div>
 <div class="div">3</div>
 <div class="div">4</div>
</div>
```