# Уровнять размеры дочерних элементов flex-родителя, которые находятся друг под другом

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Расположил дочерние элементы flex-родителя, друг под другом. Для этого задал всем абсолютное позиционирование, а одному из детей - `position:relative`. И в связи с этим появилась проблема - размеры детей, не совпадают. Тот который позиционирован относительно - имеет ожидаемые размеры. А те, которые абсолютно - нет: они больше. 
Как сделать так, чтобы абсолютно позиционированные элементы были такого же размера как и относительно позиционированный?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startSlider);
var arrImg  = [],
controlInterval,
show = 0;


function startSlider (){
var children = document.getElementById("wrap").children;

for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
 if (children[i].tagName == "DIV"){
  arrImg.push(children[i]);
 } else if (children[i].tagName == "P"){
  children[i].addEventListener("click", changeImg);
 }
}
}

function changeImg(event){
var target = event.target;
var t = arrImg.length;
if (target.className == "prev"){
 if(show == 0){
  arrImg[t-1].className = "show";
        arrImg[show].className = "hide";
        show = t-1;
 } else{
  arrImg[show-1].className = "show";
        arrImg[show].className = "hide";
        show--;
 }
} else if (target.className == "next"){
  console.log("work");
 if(show == t-1){
  arrImg[0].className = "show";
        arrImg[show].className = "hide";
        show = 0;
 } else{
  arrImg[show+1].className = "show";
        arrImg[show].className = "hide";
        show++;
 }
}
   
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  padding: 10px; 
}
#wrap div{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1s;

}
#wrap div:first-child{
  position: relative;
}

/*дальше идет оформительский код не влияющий на проблему*/
#wrap div:nth-child(2){
  background-color: red;
}
#wrap div:nth-child(3){
  background-color: yellow;
}
.prev, .next{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 45%;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.next{
  right: 0px;
}

.show{
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.hide{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
 <div class="show">1</div>
 <div class="hide">2</div>
 <div class="hide">3</div>
 <p class="prev">&#x2190</p>
 <p class="next">&#x2192</p>
</div>
```

Чтобы увидеть "баг"  - переключите слайдер.

А глобальный вопрос: почему размеры элементов, в данном случае, считаются по разному? Ведь во всех учебных пособиях сказано, что: "при использовании процентной записи ширина элемента вычисляется в зависимости от ширины родительского элемента" https://webref.ru/css/width

П.С.: в реальности у меня нет `height` для обертки слайдера ("wrap"). Высота определяется браузером автоматически - для соблюдения пропорций картинки. И когда я все позиционирую абсолютно - обертка схлопывается. А мне нужен бордер.

Comment: вот в реальности в примере и убери `height `, что-бы было понятно

Comment: `height `  нет у  `wrap` ?

Comment: @Air если я уберу высоту, то дивчики сами по себе схлопнутся. Тогда нужно искать картинки одинакового размера - пиксель в пиксель.

Comment: Я тя понял, ты хочешь что бы дочерние элементы задавали высоту родителю?

Comment: @Air, вопрос-то, на самом деле, более глобальный. Я его указал в дополнениях. Почему размеры по разному вычисляются для относительных и абсолютно позиционированных. Если бы была разница - я бы возможно и не использовал такой подход

Comment: @Air, да - чтобы высота динамически определялась.

Comment: я не знаю как у тебя в твоем проекте. Но тут  у тебя отсутствует обнуление марджинов и да еще и бордеры...

Comment: @Air, что я уже только не пытался делать: и с марджиными игрался и с `box-sizing` и т.д и т.п. - ничего не получилось

Comment: дай минутку подумать...

Comment: А картинки как ты собираешься вставлять `img ` или `background-ом`

Comment: @Air, не планировал. В смысле, вставляю  `img` )

Comment: и кстати, если хочешь использовать в слайдере картинки разных размеров, я тя будет слайдер прыгать, не красиво получиться...  хотя на вкус и цвет товарища нет

Comment: @Air, да. Но, в любом случае, чтобы слайдер не прыгал, и картинки выглядели красиво - у самих картинок должно быть одинаковое соотношение сторон.

Comment: глянь я кое что в ответе написал в начале

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не сильно вникал JS и в код в целом, но, вот вам решение вопроса:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startSlider);
var arrImg  = [],
controlInterval,
show = 0;


function startSlider (){
var children = document.getElementById("wrap").children;

for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
 if (children[i].tagName == "DIV"){
  arrImg.push(children[i]);
 } else if (children[i].tagName == "P"){
  children[i].addEventListener("click", changeImg);
 }
}
}

function changeImg(event){
var target = event.target;
var t = arrImg.length;
if (target.className == "prev"){
 if(show == 0){
  arrImg[t-1].className = "show";
        arrImg[show].className = "hide";
        show = t-1;
 } else{
  arrImg[show-1].className = "show";
        arrImg[show].className = "hide";
        show--;
 }
} else if (target.className == "next"){
  console.log("work");
 if(show == t-1){
  arrImg[0].className = "show";
        arrImg[show].className = "hide";
        show = 0;
 } else{
  arrImg[show+1].className = "show";
        arrImg[show].className = "hide";
        show++;
 }
}
   
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  padding: 10px; 
}
#wrap div{
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1s;

}
#wrap div:first-child{
width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#wrap div:not(:first-child) {
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

/*дальше идет оформительский код не влияющий на проблему*/
#wrap div:nth-child(2){
  background-color: red;
}
#wrap div:nth-child(3){
  background-color: yellow;
}
.prev, .next{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 45%;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.next{
  right: 0px;
}

.show{
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.hide{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
 <div class="show">1</div>
 <div class="hide">2</div>
 <div class="hide">3</div>
 <p class="prev">&#x2190</p>
 <p class="next">&#x2192</p>
</div>
```

Отвечая на вопрос про позиционирование `absolute` и `relative`. При абсолютном позиционировании, задавая блоку 100% ширину и высоту вы задаете размеры родителя, без использования `padding`. Для решения проблемы вам было достаточно убрать ширину и задать абсолютно позиционированным элементам отступы со всех сторон. Еще одним вариантом было использование стиля `calc`.

Comment: Гениально, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот такую конструкцию изваять, но придется твой JS переписать, так как работать не будет

```
<div id="wrap"> этому задай определенную высоту, как ни как она тебе нужна
<div id="innerWrap"> засунь в обертку еще одну  и этот элемент растяни флексом родителя
  <div class="mainShow show">1</div>
  <div class="mainShow hide">2</div>
  <div class="mainShow hide">3</div>
  <p class="prev">&#x2190</p>
  <p class="next">&#x2192</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Зачем тебе `flex` и `position: absolute;` выбери или первый или второй...
 в данном случае `position: absolute;` лучше...

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startSlider);
var arrImg = [],
  controlInterval,
  show = 0;


function startSlider() {
  var children = document.getElementById("wrap").children;

  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if (children[i].tagName == "DIV") {
      arrImg.push(children[i]);
    } else if (children[i].tagName == "P") {
      children[i].addEventListener("click", changeImg);
    }
  }
}

function changeImg(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var t = arrImg.length;
  if (target.className == "prev") {
    if (show == 0) {
      arrImg[t - 1].className = "show";
      arrImg[show].className = "hide";
      show = t - 1;
    } else {
      arrImg[show - 1].className = "show";
      arrImg[show].className = "hide";
      show--;
    }
  } else if (target.className == "next") {
    console.log("work");
    if (show == t - 1) {
      arrImg[0].className = "show";
      arrImg[show].className = "hide";
      show = 0;
    } else {
      arrImg[show + 1].className = "show";
      arrImg[show].className = "hide";
      show++;
    }
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}

#wrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40%;
  min-height:200px;
  display:flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  
}
#innerWrap{
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin:5px 0 0 px;
  display:inline-block;
  
}

 #innerWrap div {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1s;
}


/*дальше идет оформительский код не влияющий на проблему*/

#innerWrap div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

 #innerWrap div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 45%;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.next {
  right: 0px;
}

.show {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="innerWrap">
  <div class="mainShow show">1</div>
  <div class="mainShow hide">2</div>
  <div class="mainShow hide">3</div>
  <p class="prev">&#x2190</p>
  <p class="next">&#x2192</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: )) в реальности у меня нет `height` для обертки слайдера. Высота определяется браузером автоматически - для соблюдения пропорций картинка. И когда я все позиционирую абсолютно - обертка схлопывается. А мне нужен бордер. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785660/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-flex-box-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B5

Comment: внес дополнение в вопрос

Comment: Ну тебя в примере  `height`...  Я исходил из того, что было...  а почему щас не схлопывается...?

Comment: Потому что, для примера я использую `div`, и поэтому я явно определил им высоту. Мой провтык, не обратил на это внимание)

Comment: Ну тогда правь вопрос, опиши нормально и будем решать, что делать и как добиться того, что пришло в твою гениальную головушку...)))  заинтриговал...)))

Comment: )) уже внес исправления.  "за дурною головою и ногам нэма покою"

Comment: Да, с дополнительной оберткой смотрится намного лучше, особенно, если для `innerWrap` установить `overflow:hidden`.  Но глобально проблема не решена. Абсолютно позиционированные - все равно больше. В данном случае на  1px.  Я приму этот ответ - но задам еще 1 - уже глобальный.

Comment: Когда вопрос задашь,  скинь ссылку

Comment: не успел я задать другой вопрос. Ответ дали тут. Вынужден изменить принятие ответа)

Comment: Не страшно... все ок