# Как реализовать карусель на чистом Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Ищу реализацию циклирующегося слайдера-карусели.

Все реализации которые я находил сделаны на JQuery или плагином для WordPress и этим они мне не подходят.

Подскажите реализацию плавного JS слайдера-карусели, в котором на экране отображаются 3 элемента и крайние заходят на половину за экран:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.item'),
    translate = 0;

    elements[0].onclick = OnclickLeftFunction;
    elements[2].onclick = OnclickRightFunction;
    function OnclickLeftFunction(){
        translate -= 47.5;
        elements[0].style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "vw)";
        elements[1].style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "vw)";
        elements[2].style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "vw)";
    }
    function OnclickRightFunction(){
        translate += 47.5;
        elements[0].style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "vw)";
        elements[1].style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "vw)";
        elements[2].style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "vw)";
    }
```

```css
container{
  width:95vw;
  height: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: gold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.item{
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  color:white;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 1s linear;
}
.item:first-child{
margin-left:-100px;
}
.item:last-child{
margin-right:-100px;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</container>
```

Где при нажатии на левый блок все блоки смещаются на место блока слева от себя и наоборот для правого блока.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785839/%d0%a3%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-flex-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d1%80 - не совсем та карусель, но карусель

Comment: Через Opacity сделать достаточно просто, но как я понимаю здесь нужно через transform: translate сделать, что бы была анимация сдвига влево или сдвига вправо

Comment: В этом и основная проблема

Comment: У меня по крайней мере

Comment: ну так покажите Ваш js

Comment: Добавил как они должны перемещатся, но с циклированием элементов у меня проблема

Comment: При нажатии на 1 и 3 блок они сдвигаются влево и направо соответственно

Comment: И из-за экрана должен слева или справа так же сдвигатся элемент

Comment: А тот элемент который вышел за экран должен передать событые onclick  тому, который остался крайним